# Countifs in between ranges

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm struggling to pull below conditions together. I'd like to have a formula that will count values between `1` and `5` only when cell U13 contains the text `1-5`.

```
=COUNTIFS(U13,"1-5")
```

---

```
=COUNTIFS(K2:K22,">=1",K2:K22, "<=5")
```

Answer (score 0):

- do it like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((K2:K22>=1) * (K23:K22<=5) * (U13="1-5"), 1, )))
  ```